# How to obtain the download url for a document library content programmatically

Tags: liferay

I have several contents in my document library (images, documents, videos...) and I want to obtain the download url for each of them programmatically, so I can show them on a jsp in a custom portlet.

Investigating, I have found this page with a possible solution:
https://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/11073293
but I'm not comfortable with it, since it implies building the url manually with several parameters.

I would like to know if there is a better way ("Liferay way") to do this.

Comment: For example, to build a login url you could do it manually with a string '/c/portal/login' and obtaning the p_l_id and concatenating... but instead of doing this manually, you can call themeDisplay.getURLSignIn() and Liferay builds it for you. I'm looking for something similar in this case.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am afraid but that is the liferay way :-).

If you still need more confirmation check out [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.liferay.portal/portal-service/6.1.0/com/liferay/portlet/documentlibrary/util/DLUtil.java#DLUtil.getPreviewURL%28com.liferay.portal.kernel.repository.model.FileEntry,com.liferay.portal.kernel.repository.model.FileVersion,com.liferay.portal.theme.ThemeDisplay,java.lang.String,boolean%29) of the [`DLUtil#getPreviewURL`](http://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.1/javadocs/com/liferay/portlet/documentlibrary/util/DLUtil.html#getPreviewURL%28com.liferay.portal.kernel.repository.model.FileEntry,%20com.liferay.portal.kernel.repository.model.FileVersion,%20com.liferay.portal.theme.ThemeDisplay,%20java.lang.String,%20boolean,%20boolean%29) method.

This method has been used by liferay's `Documents & Media portlet` and `Document and Media display portlet`. Also you can check-out the JSP source as to how these portlets use the above method [`/portal-web/docroot/html/portlet/document_library/action/download.jspf`](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/master/portal-web/docroot/html/portlet/document_library/action/download.jspf#L20) .

**P.S.:**

You can convert `DLFileEntry` to `FileEntry` with this [static method](http://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.1/javadocs/com/liferay/portlet/documentlibrary/service/DLAppServiceUtil.html#getFileEntry%28long%29).

Comment: Thanks Prakash, I am not uncomfortable using the Liferay way, as long as I can use a method like DLUtil.getPreviewURL from my code and abstract from the detail. What I was uncomfortable with, was having to build the url myself manually.

Comment: However, I am working with DLFileEntry objects, and DLUtil.getPreviewURL expects a FileEntry object. How do I get around this? I'm trying to cast from DLFileEntry, but that's giving me an error. Any ideas?

Comment: check this static method: http://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.1/javadocs/com/liferay/portlet/documentlibrary/service/DLAppServiceUtil.html#getFileEntry%28long%29

Comment: Thanks! That was exactly what I was missing

Comment: This is a great solution, I always used to do it similar to how Mark suggests in the other answer by building the url using folder and group IDs!

Comment: As of Liferay 7.2.x,  DLUtil#getPreviewURL is deprecated and replaced by https://docs.liferay.com/ce/apps/document-library/2.0.0/javadocs/com/liferay/document/library/util/DLURLHelper.html#getPreviewURL-com.liferay.portal.kernel.repository.model.FileEntry-com.liferay.portal.kernel.repository.model.FileVersion-com.liferay.portal.kernel.theme.ThemeDisplay-java.lang.String-boolean-boolean-

Answer (score 6):

By such questions I see always to Liferay sources. Here is the fragment that build the file download url in "Documents and Media Library" portlet:

```
<liferay-ui:input-resource
   url='<%= themeDisplay.getPortalURL() + themeDisplay.getPathContext() + "/documents/" + themeDisplay.getScopeGroupId() + StringPool.SLASH + fileEntry.getUuid() %>'
/>
```

but you are right, i would prefer a methode like DLFile.getUrl() too.