# Liferay Document Management

Tags: version-control, liferay, document-management

I am totally new to liferay.

i have created Liferay portlet in which i need to uploaded document

I used DLUtil.addFile method to upload document from webservice and from local. I also succeed in uploading it. But the problem comes when I tried to upload the document again. It shows com.liferay.portlet.documentlibrary.DuplicateFileException

my code is

```
        long companyId = serviceContext.getCompanyId();
        File sampleChapter = (File) serviceContext.getAttribute("sampleChapter");
            String folderName = "Sample_Chapters";
            LMSUtil.createFolder(folderName, companyId);
            String filePath = folderName+StringPool.SLASH+fileName;
            System.out.println(filePath);
            try {
                DLStoreUtil.addFile(companyId, CompanyConstants.SYSTEM, filePath, sampleChapter);


            } catch (PortalException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (SystemException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

And the error I got is

```
com.liferay.portlet.documentlibrary.DuplicateFileException: D:\rajkumar\softwares\liferay\liferay-portal-6.2-ce-ga2\data\document_library\10154\0\Sample_Chapters\hello1.txt\1.0
    at com.liferay.portlet.documentlibrary.store.FileSystemStore.addFile(FileSystemStore.java:76)
    at com.liferay.portlet.documentlibrary.store.BaseStore.addFile(BaseStore.java:109)
    at com.liferay.portlet.documentlibrary.store.StoreProxyImpl.addFile(StoreProxyImpl.java:55)
    at com.liferay.portlet.documentlibrary.store.SafeFileNameStoreWrapper.addFile(SafeFileNameStoreWrapper.java:73)
    at com.liferay.portlet.documentlibrary.store.DLStoreImpl.addFile(DLStoreImpl.java:108)
    at com.liferay.portlet.documentlibrary.store.DLStoreImpl.addFile(DLStoreImpl.java:184)
    at com.liferay.portlet.documentlibrary.store.DLStoreUtil.addFile(DLStoreUtil.java:187)
    at com.slayer.service.impl.LMSBookLocalServiceImpl.attachFiles(LMSBookLocalServiceImpl.java:154)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:115)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.transaction.DefaultTransactionExecutor.execute(DefaultTransactionExecutor.java:62)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.transaction.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:51)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:111)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanAopProxy.invoke(ServiceBeanAopProxy.java:175)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy414.attachFiles(Unknown Source)
    at com.slayer.service.impl.LMSBookServiceImpl.attachFiles(LMSBookServiceImpl.java:90)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:115)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.transaction.DefaultTransactionExecutor.execute(DefaultTransactionExecutor.java:62)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.transaction.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:51)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:111)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMethodAdvice.java:56)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:111)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanAopProxy.invoke(ServiceBeanAopProxy.java:175)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy415.attachFiles(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.liferay.portal.jsonwebservice.JSONWebServiceActionImpl._invokeActionMethod(JSONWebServiceActionImpl.java:318)
    at com.liferay.portal.jsonwebservice.JSONWebServiceActionImpl.invoke(JSONWebServiceActionImpl.java:71)
    at com.liferay.portal.jsonwebservice.JSONWebServiceServiceAction.getJSON(JSONWebServiceServiceAction.java:66)
    at com.liferay.portal.struts.JSONAction.execute(JSONAction.java:78)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.JSONServlet.service(JSONServlet.java:70)
    at com.liferay.portal.jsonwebservice.JSONWebServiceServlet.service(JSONWebServiceServlet.java:71)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PortalClassLoaderServlet.service(PortalClassLoaderServlet.java:103)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.bean.ClassLoaderBeanHandler.invoke(ClassLoaderBeanHandler.java:67)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy518.doFilter(Unknown Source)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:165)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:96)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PortalClassLoaderFilter.doFilter(PortalClassLoaderFilter.java:74)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.bean.ClassLoaderBeanHandler.invoke(ClassLoaderBeanHandler.java:67)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy518.doFilter(Unknown Source)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:169)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.authverifier.AuthVerifierFilter.processFilter(AuthVerifierFilter.java:169)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PortalClassLoaderFilter.doFilter(PortalClassLoaderFilter.java:74)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.bean.ClassLoaderBeanHandler.invoke(ClassLoaderBeanHandler.java:67)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy518.doFilter(Unknown Source)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:165)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:96)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PortalClassLoaderFilter.doFilter(PortalClassLoaderFilter.java:74)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilter.doFilter(InvokerFilter.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

All I need is versioning of documents uploaded. Please anyone help me in resolving the problem. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just from glancing at the API,  you'll want to check if [hasFile](http://cdn.docs.liferay.com/portal/6.1/javadocs/com/liferay/portlet/documentlibrary/store/DLStoreUtil.html#hasFile%28long,%20long,%20java.lang.String%29) then [updateFile](http://cdn.docs.liferay.com/portal/6.1/javadocs/com/liferay/portlet/documentlibrary/store/DLStoreUtil.html#updateFile%28long,%20long,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20boolean,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.io.File%29) else [addFile](http://cdn.docs.liferay.com/portal/6.1/javadocs/com/liferay/portlet/documentlibrary/store/DLStoreUtil.html#addFile%28long,%20long,%20java.lang.String,%20boolean,%20java.io.File%29)

---

I'm performing a similar operation using a different API ([DLAppServiceUtil](http://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.2/javadocs/com/liferay/portlet/documentlibrary/service/DLAppServiceUtil.html)) and given that the needed parameters are less when using [DLStoreUtil](http://cdn.docs.liferay.com/portal/6.1/javadocs/com/liferay/portlet/documentlibrary/store/DLStoreUtil.html#addFile%28long,%20long,%20java.lang.String,%20boolean,%20java.io.File%29), I'm going to investigate converting to this approach.

**Edit**: I'm not able to see the folders/directores in the `Documents and Media` portlet that are added through `DLStoreUtil`. I have verified they are uploading correctly into the `/data/document_library` directory. For my particular case I'll want to stick with `DLAppServiceUtil` due to the requirement that the files be managed via that portlet after being uploaded through my custom portlet.

See Also: [How do I use the different file storage and retrieval APIs in Liferay?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12903778/how-do-i-use-the-different-file-storage-and-retrieval-apis-in-liferay)

Answer (score 0):

When you are uploading the file at that time you should have to save the file with datetime so next time you are uploading same file it will not throw duplicate file exception.

You have to override the Document and Media Portlet and writing a code for saving the file you should have to mention datetime with file.

once you done then deploy the code on server.

Thanks & Regards,
Anil Kumar Shrivastava